# How to get jwt token from Authorization

Tags: spring, kotlin, jwt

I'm sending the request with jwt token in Authorization. I need to fetch it somehow and I tried by this way:

```kotlin
@GetMapping
fun getUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal jwt: Jwt<*, *>): ResponseEntity<UserDto?> {
   val allClaimsFromToken: Claims? = getAllClaimsFromToken(jwt.toString());
   val userNameFromJwtToken: Any? = allClaimsFromToken?.get("sub");
   ....
}
```

Unfortunately I get all the time null as jwt variable. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the first question is how are you receiving the token? Are you using spring security OAuth2? Or is it just a header that gets passed?

Comment: @ced-b it's just header through Authorization field in postman

Comment: Ok, that's simple enough, what library are you using for JWT?

Comment: @ced-b using jjwt

Comment: Ok, see below and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most straight forward way of doing this would be to get the raw header value and then parse it with JJWT.

```kotlin
@GetMapping
fun getUser(@RequestHeader (name="Authorization") tokenEncoded: String): ResponseEntity<UserDto?> {
   Jwt myToken = Jwts.parserBuilder()    
     .setSigningKey(yourKeyHere)
     .build()
     .parseClaimsJws(tokenEncoded.removePrefix("Bearer").trim());

   // do something
}
```

You could also look into using the Spring library for OAuth2 it automates a bit more. Or you can create a filter that does the parsing so you don't have to repeat this on every web call.

Also see this post for further ideas [Accessing JWT Token from a Spring Boot Rest Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54909509/2649570) . It's Java, but basically the same applies.