# How to declaratively use authorization with JWT in Spring 5 controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

There is a simple web service with one endpoint `"GET /hello"`.
It would be good to **declaratively** describe in the controller that a JWT is expected in order to extract from it some data about the authorized user making the request.

Exploring some open source projects on Github, I see that the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` annotation is somehow involved in the process. However, none of the tutorials I've managed to find mention such a declarative approach - they mostly show how to create a JWT, not how to deal with one.
*I will be grateful if you point out noteworthy examples that I missed.*

Obviously the problem is trivial and related to the basic capabilities of Spring Security, but I can't put the puzzle togeher.

Please, help me to find a **proper (natural) way to pass JWT into the controller and get data from it**.
Could you share a working example with dependencies and a small test showing how to work with JWT in controller?

`SpringBoot 2.4.0`

```
import org.springframework.   ???   .Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;


@RestController 
public class MyController {
 
    @GetMapping("hello")
    public Object getRequests(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
      
      String name = getPropertyFromJwt(jwt, "name");
      String id = getPropertyFromJwt(jwt, "id");
      
      return Map.of("name", name, "id", id);
    }
}
```

Comment: everything you need is here:
https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

if you want to read the JWT as is(In base64) add 

HttpServletRequest request

as method paramter: (public Object getRequests(<other parameters>, HttpServletRequest request)  ) and call

request.getHeader("authorization");

then you will have the JWT directly

Comment: another option to access the header directly(using @RequestHeader annotation):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911059/3942132

Comment: @RoieBeck Ok, we have that header as String. What next, how to parse it?

Comment: https://jwt.io/ gives you a list of all the frameworks for java :) , https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt  maven package is an example, search for "Decode a Token" in the github page, it is really simple. each library got it's own way to decode a JWT, you can also do Base64.decode to jwt body(second part of the JWT is also called payload) yourself :),
as a genreral rule, I think you need to understand JWT better before using it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving deeper I've found out that the question consists of
the three:

1. How to parse JWT string into an object?
2. How to pass the object into a controller method?
3. What is the standard/default way in sping boot to do that?

Here are the short answers:

1. Use any library you like to convert encoded JWT into an object.
   One of them is [com.auth0:java-jwt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt).
2. Parameter annotated with `@AuthenticationPrincipal` can be of any type `X`
   and it comes from `currentSecurityContext.getAuthorization().getPrincipal()`
   where `currentSecurityContext` is of type `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext`.
   In WebFlux configuration it comes from invocation of `ServerSecurityContextRepository.load(...)`
   for every request (see implementation below).
3. I did not manage to find the answer for the #3, but had realized that
   there are several open source ad-hoc implementations (good and bad) of this concern.
   After all I've ended up implementing another one just to understand the pitfals.

Please, find a sample minimal working project [here](https://github.com/diziaq/sample-so-question-65868747).

The key points are:

- A. Configuration using an implementation of `ServerSecurityContextRepository`

  ```
  @EnableWebFluxSecurity
  public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
      ServerSecurityContextRepository repo = createContextRepository();

      return http
                 .authorizeExchange(e -> e.anyExchange().authenticated())
                 .securityContextRepository(repo)
                 .build();
     }
  }
  ```
- B. Create implementation of `Authentication` interface and a function (or chain of functions) `ServerWebExchange -> Authentication` that should be applied in `ServerSecurityContextRepository.load` method and inserted into a `SecurityContext` (i.e. `SecurityContextImpl`) of each server request.
- C. Principal can be any object on your choice. Return it from `Authentication.getPrincipal()` method of the implemetation created in (B).

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate successfully , the request must be authenticated by a `AuthenticationProvider` . Once it  successfully authenticates , it will return a `Authentication` object which contain a principal object.

`@AuthenticationPrincipal` just helps to access this principle object. However, spring-security does not provide a `AuthenticationProvider` that can authenticate with JWT out of the box, that means you have to implement by yourself. In your customised `AuthenticationProvider` , you verify the JWT and decode the property that you are interested and create a customised principal object that hold these properties such that you can access them by `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

Just have a quick google and found this [example](https://github.com/Mercateo/spring-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mercateo/spring/security/jwt/security/JWTAuthenticationProvider.java) may help you.

Comment: Thank you Ken Chan. I believe this example can lead me the right way. Generally, don't you find it strange that every app is supposed to implement its own AuthenticationProvider from scratch, although the very area of auth is so standardized. I would expect to see at least a basic implementation of this "JWT concern" in a SpringBoot starter. And it seems to me that for WebFlux there will be additional troubles with the same stuff.