# How to add customer header to Request?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm caught in a situation where I need to manually add a **header**(`Authorization`) to the request.

**The catch is that I only need to add that header to requests coming to a specific API(`Controller`). *Not to all*.**

*I'm using Java 1.8 with Spring Boot.*

Is there anyway to achieve this?

I want to achieve this : [Image description](https://ibb.co/VVK0dMf)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you..

```
public class MyCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().equals("Your custom URI")){
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Authorization","Your value");
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
}
}
```

For every request, checks the URI and if matches,adds the Authorization header.Also, you will probably need to add @Component annotation.

Comment: Thanks Vasilis. I'll try this. Btw I am already using OncePerRequestFilter for JWT authentication for my Application. Is it fine to use multiple OncePerRequestFilter or should I just implement this on same old filter?

Comment: I am not really sure, but I suppose you can implement it on same OncePerRequestFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is the answer that you are looking for:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<AppUser> getUsers(OAuth2Authentication auth, @RequestHeader (name="Authorization") String token)
```

More info here is the reference of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54911059/13842927

I hope that this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but in my case user's not setting header from the UI. It must set at the backend somehow.

Comment: Your welcome, but API is a two-way street, you send something and you get a response, so if your user sign-in it gets a token as a response which you are saving in the cookies or session or in whatever way. So please specify your problem with more details :)

Comment: To be more specific, the API on to which I need to add header is provided by a 3rd party dependency(java-melody). So when I hit that URL from browser I need to add header of authorization token manually on backend. I am also attaching an image. Please follow updated question.